# I am getting an error while trying to install macaca to inspect elements in iOS app using Appium 1.6.4

Tags: ios, testing, appium, appium-ios

```
>> xctest-client start with port: 8900
```

> > WebDriverAgent version: 1.1.6
> >     app-inspector:66:44 [master] pid:5022 undefined
> >     (node:5022) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: >> app-inspector:66:44 [master] pid:5022 undefined

Above is the error I get. Any solution or way to get it installed. Are there any other option to inspect elements  for iOS app .

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with Macaca inspector.

Now I'm using [Appium iOS Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector):

- download this repository
- stop application during running test (e.g. set breakpoint in debug mode)
- open "iOS Inspector.html" file in browser

And you will see app xml structure.

Comment: I downloaded the zip but it does not seem to work. I start the appium server using 127.0.0.1:4723 . Then opening the ios inspector.html gives this error: "Appium session at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub is unreachable. Make sure your Appium test is running and click this message to retry." Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: You have to start appium server, run your test and stop it in some point (by setting breakpoint in debug mode) and only there you should open inspector.html